# Power series on complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to find a power series that converges for at least one complex number z with $\lvert z \rvert= 1 $ and diverges for at least one z with $\lvert z \rvert= 1 $
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{z^{n}}{n}$.

Comment: for which complex z does this converge?

Comment: $z=1$. And it converges on the boundary except $z=1$.

Comment: but i need it to converge at z=1

Comment: Don't you put $|z|=1$ instead of $z=1$?

Comment: my bad i misunderstood what you were saying. thanks